# How to create a rolling window in pandas with another condition

Tags: python, pandas, rolling-computation

I have a data frame with 2 columns

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 2)), columns=list('AB'))


    A   B
0   11  10
1   61  30
2   24  54
3   47  52
4   72  42
... ... ...
95  61  2
96  67  41
97  95  30
98  29  66
99  49  22
100 rows × 2 columns
```

Now I want to create a third column, which is a rolling window max of col 'A' BUT
the max has to be lower than the corresponding value in col 'B'. In other words I want the value of the 4 (using a window size of 4) in column 'A' closest to the value in col 'B', yet smaller than B

So for example in row
3   47  52
the new value I am looking for, is not 61 but 47, because it is the highest value of the 4 that is not higher than 52

pseudo code

```
df['C'] = df['A'].rolling(window=4).max()  where < df['B']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `concat` + `shift` to create a wide DataFrame with the previous values, which makes complicated rolling calculations a bit easier.

#### Sample Data

```
np.random.seed(42)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(100, 2)), columns=list('AB'))
```

#### Code

```
N = 4
# End slice ensures same default min_periods behavior to `.rolling`
df1 = pd.concat([df['A'].shift(i).rename(i) for i in range(N)], axis=1).iloc[N-1:]

# Remove values larger than B, then find the max of remaining.
df['C'] = df1.where(df1.lt(df.B, axis=0)).max(1)
```

---

```
print(df.head(15))

     A   B     C
0   51  92   NaN  # Missing b/c min_periods
1   14  71   NaN  # Missing b/c min_periods
2   60  20   NaN  # Missing b/c min_periods
3   82  86  82.0
4   74  74  60.0
5   87  99  87.0
6   23   2   NaN  # Missing b/c 82, 74, 87, 23 all > 2
7   21  52  23.0  # Max of 21, 23, 87, 74 which is < 52
8    1  87  23.0
9   29  37  29.0
10   1  63  29.0
11  59  20   1.0
12  32  75  59.0
13  57  21   1.0
14  88  48  32.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom function to `.apply` to the rolling window.  In this case, you can use a default argument to pass in the `B` column.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 2)), columns=('AB'))

def rollup(a, B=df.B):
    ix = a.index.max()
    b = B[ix]
    return a[a<b].max()

df['C'] = df.A.rolling(4).apply(rollup)

df
# returns:
     A   B     C
0    8  17   NaN
1   23  84   NaN
2   75  84   NaN
3   86  24  23.0
4   52  83  75.0
..  ..  ..   ...
95  38  22   NaN
96  53  48  38.0
97  45   4   NaN
98   3  92  53.0
99  91  86  53.0
```

The `NaN` values occur when no number in the window of A is less than B or at the start of the series when the window is too big for the first few rows.

Comment: Why is `df.loc[3, 'C'] == 23.0` and not `== 75.0`?

Comment: The value of `df.loc[3, 'C']` is calculated as the maximum value of `df.loc[0:4, 'A'] == [8, 23, 75, 86]` that is less than `df.loc[3, 'B'] == 24', which is how we get `23`.

Comment: While this seems to do the job, I phased out using ".apply" due to performance considerations for large data sets a while ago. This may have improved in the meantime, not sure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `where` to replace values that don't fulfill the condition with `np.nan` and then use `rolling(window=4, min_periods=1)`:

```
In [37]: df['C'] = df['A'].where(df['A'] < df['B'], np.nan).rolling(window=4, min_periods=1).max()                                                                                            

In [38]: df                                                                                                                                                                                   
Out[38]: 
    A   B    C
0   0   1  0.0
1   1   2  1.0
2   2   3  2.0
3  10   4  2.0
4   4   5  4.0
5   5   6  5.0
6  10   7  5.0
7  10   8  5.0
8  10   9  5.0
9  10  10  NaN
```