# Rolling Semivariance in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, rolling-computation

I am trying to compute a rolling semivariance or semi std in a pandas series.

It all comes down to adding a condition, that replaces all values in the rolling window with NaN and then computing the standard deviation / variance in that window (or just filter out the values in the window).

So what I am looking for is something like this:

```
x = stock_prices.pct_change()
window = 10
rol_mean = x.rolling(window).mean()

sem_std = x.rolling(window)[x.rolling(window)<rol_mean].std()
```

But of course this throws an error as 'Series' object has no attribute 'columns' and '>' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'Rolling'.

pseudocode:
`rol_sem_std = x.rolling(window=10).std()  where < x.rolling(window=10).mean()`

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Why don't you compute `x.rolling(window=10).std()` and the corresponding mean, then NaN out the values that don't fill your condition?

Comment: That way I wouldn't really compute the semi std, would I? I need to compute std from values in the rolling window that are lower than the mean of the window.
Posted a solution that worked for me below.

Comment: Ok, then I read your pseudocode wrong. Well that sounds easy to compute from a series too? So if you know how given a series, how to compute the semi std - then you use .rolling().apply() with that function - it gets a series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know, given a series, how to compute the semi std - then you use .rolling().apply() with that function.

Using the definition from https://www.investopedia.com/terms/s/semideviation.asp

[image: semi-deviation formula]

We *cannot* use the built-in `std` because we need to use the whole group average, but only compute deviations based on those observations in the group that are below the average.

Looks like we'll need to define the semi-deviation as a function:

```
import numpy as np

def semi_std(ser):
    average = np.nanmean(ser)
    r_below = ser[ser < average]
    return np.sqrt(1/len(r_below) * np.sum((average - r_below)**2))

x.rolling(window).apply(semi_std, raw=True)

# using raw=True speeds up the computation - this is applicable
# if the function works well with a numpy array instead of a Series
# also, if possible, investigate using numba.
```

I think for maximum robustness, probably add a condition that if `len(r_below) == 0` then the result is 0 or NaN (it's a matter of definition - but 0 is probably the reasonable choice).

Comment: This works great! A little bit slow but does the trick. Did not even notice that you can't really use std() in this situation, since it uses wrong mean. Thank you:)

Comment: For increased speed I think you can pass `raw=True` to `apply`. The effect is that the function gets a numpy array instead of a series, and it works fine in this case. One thing to look out for when using `raw=True` is otherwise missing value handling and indexing.

Comment: And even faster with `@numba.njit` on the function too, at least in a brief experiment.

Comment: @MedvidekPu Fast enough with raw=True or numba?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is actually pretty simple if one knows how rolling windows work in Pandas. The trick here is to use the shift function on the dataframe first which shifts each row by one position so it becomes the last element of the previous row. Then we can do our rolling mean calculation without having any issues with type conversion etc.

```
import pandas as pd

from datetime import timedelta

df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.randn(5, 4), index=pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=5))

df.index = df.index + timedelta(days=10)

print(df)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! I am not sure if this helps me with my solution though. I can easily calculate the rolling mean, but I have problem with calculating rolling semi standard deviation as I need to filter out values lower than the rolling mean in the particular windows and then taking a standard deviation from that window.
The solution should return a pandas series with first 10 values missing and then semivariances.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution using this previous thread: [How to create a rolling window in pandas with another condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60765866/how-to-create-a-rolling-window-in-pandas-with-another-condition)

```
N = 10
# End slice ensures same default min_periods behavior to `.rolling`
df1 = pd.concat([x.shift(i).rename(i) for i in range(N)], axis=1).iloc[:]

# Remove values larger than B, then find the max of remaining.
df = df1.where(df1.lt(rol_mean, axis=0)).std(1)
```

Comment: This is a wrong computation of semivariance (see creanion's answer).
Altough, this works faster than the apply function. Hence for different conditions might be useful.